# Is looping an array to compare to itself considered O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithms, language-agnostic, big-o

Often when I'm doing an operation comparing an array to itself, I write code along these lines:

```
function operation (array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      // do something with array, i, and j
    }
  }
}
```

While the runtime of this code (starting `j` at `i + 1`) is clearly faster than a normal double-nested loop, I'm struggling to figure out if that's just a matter of a smaller coefficient or if it should be represented by a different big O.

Is there a better big O for the above function than n squared?

Comment: @gnat I'm checking that out right now to see if it touches on this type of case

Comment: @JohnWu hmm, I'm familiar with O(n log n) in the context of sorting algorithms, I suspected that might be the complexity of this function...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about algorithmic complexity without a cost model and a machine model. Or, in other words: it doesn't make sense to count things if you don't define what the things are that you are counting.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: you're putting the bar unnecessarily high. Whatever OP is doing is going to be *at least* proportional to the number of loop iterations. Possibly more, but it still makes sense to talk about that first.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Depending on the machine model, `array.length` might have a worst-case step complexity of Θ(#elements) pointer dereferences, for example. So, if we are counting pointer dereferences, and are in such a machine model, then the whole thing is *at least* O(n³).

Comment: @JohnWu No, it is still n^2.  It only becomes n log n when you recurse on a fraction and not a subtraction.

Comment: You are showing nothing in the loop that depends on or takes advantage of being sorted.  It is just ordinary loop nesting: n * n/2 ==> O(n^2).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's still O(n^2), with a constant coefficient of 1/2.

The number of times the inner loop is executed is `(i-1) + (i-2) + (i-3) ... + 3 + 2 + 1` with the total number of terms being `i`. Note that the first and last term add up to `i`, as do the second and second-to-last, etc. So there are `i/2` pairs, each of which adds up to `i` - which makes a total of `i/2 * i = 1/2 * i^2`

This is actually the idea famously used by an elementary school aged Carl Friedrich Gauss circa 1785 to [outwit his teacher on a make-work assignment](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/384/did-gauss-find-the-formula-for-123-ldotsn-2n-1n-in-elementary-school).

Comment: Your first-term-plus-last-term line of thinking makes the 0.5 coefficient obvious, this is great

Comment: I don't know software.SE as well as I do SO and I suspect I'm off topic here; do you suggest I delete my own question?

Comment: @RobbieWxyz: Don't worry about the question. And the problem is actually a very famous one, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you *know* that the data is sorted, you would most certainly use a more intelligent algorithm, such as "binary search."

If you "brute-force loop through the array, without any consideration of its known properties," then of course you richly deserve your fate.